# I'm making a clicker game on python (not on pygame) and i'm having issues which i don't know how to explain

Tags: python

So I am very new to python and I think I am confident enough to make a simple clicker game, like cookie clicker. So I want to make it so you can buy upgrades but I don't really know how, here is some of my code:

```py
points = 0
doubleClick = False

while True:
    # FUNCTIONS
    def shopItems():
        global points

        userBuy = input("Enter full name of product: ")
        if userBuy.upper() == 'DOUBLE CLICK':
            if points > 10:
                print()
                print(f"Successfully bought {userBuy}")
                doubleClick == True
            else:
                print("You dont have enough points.")


    # IF STATEMENTS
    userInput = input('')
    if userInput == '':
        points += 1
        print(points)
    elif doubleClick == True:
        points += 2
        points - 10
```

Now the Double Click does not work, when I buy it, the scores still always just go up by 1 and the score doesn't go down when I buy it. I need some help.

Edit:
This wasn't the full code, here is the full code, it was changed a little bit

```py
points = 0
doubleClick = False
print("\nPress enter (or hold if you are a cheater) to add 1 point to your score")
print("\nType \"cmds\" to get a list of commands")
print()

while True:
    # FUNCTIONS
    print(doubleClick)
    def shopItems():
        global points
        global doubleClick
        print()
        print("| NAME | \t\t\t | COST | \t\t | DESCRIPTION |")
        print()
        print("| DOUBLE CLICK | \t | 100 | \t\t | 2 POINTS FOR 1 CLICK |")

        print()
        userBuy = input("Enter full name of product: ")
        if userBuy.upper() == 'DOUBLE CLICK':
            if points > 100:
                print(f"\nSuccessfully bought {userBuy}")
                doubleClick = True
                print(doubleClick)
            else:
                print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nYou dont have enough points.")
        else:
            print("\nInvalid input")

    def cmdsList():
        print("| Shop |")
# ctrl alt

    # IF STATEMENTS
    userInput = input('')
    if userInput == '':
        points += 1
        print(points)
    elif userInput.lower() == 'cmds':
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        cmdsList()
    elif userInput.lower() == 'shop':
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        shopItems()

    elif doubleClick == True:
        points += 2
        points - 100
```

Edit 2: I fixed it, I changed the `points - 100` to `points -= 100` and now it takes away 100 each time i buy the upgrade, I also had to change from this `if userInput == '':` to this `if userInput == '' and doubleClick == False:` and from this `elif userInput == '':` to this `elif userInput == '' and doubleClick == True:`

Comment: Is this the full code?  You are never calling `shopItems` anywhere.

Comment: `doubleClick == True` should be `doubleClick = True` if you want to change the value.  Otherwise you are just evaluating a line like `True` or `False`, and not changing state.

Comment: Also, you should remove points when you buy doubleclick, or you will just drain infinite points once they buy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your function `shopItems` defined, but you don't call it anywhere in the body. Also, you don't `return` anything from your function `shopItems`. The variable `doubleClick` is only a local variable of the function, but won't be known to the rest of the program. You should consider making it `global` as in the case of the variable `points`.